# Expand unique values of a column into multiple columns, for X columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, data-cleaning

I need to convert a DataFrame in the following shape:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# input DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three'],
   'tak': ['dgad', 'dgad', 'dgad', 'ogfagas', 'ogfagas', 'ogfagas', 'adgadg', 'adgadg', 'adgadg'],
   'bar': ['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
   'nix': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'Z', 'G', 'G']
})
```

... into a DataFrame where `foo` and `tak` are the index (there's never more than one unique value of `tak` for each unique value of `foo`). For `bar` and `nix` (and I actually have 10 different columns I need to do this with), I need to somehow pivot each of those columns into multiple columns where `bar_1` would be the first unique value from `bar` for each index, and `bar_2` would be the second unique value from `bar` for each `foo` group, etc. for each column. If there's only one or no unique values in `bar` or `nix` for a given `foo` group, there should be a `np.nan` inserted. Like this:

```
# desired output DataFrame
pd.DataFrame({
   'foo': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
   'tak': ['dgad', 'ogfagas', 'adgadg'],
   'bar_one': ['B', 'C', 'C'],
   'bar_two': ['A', 'A', np.nan],
   'nix_one': ['Z' , 'G', 'Z'],
   'nix_two': [np.nan, np.nan, 'G']
})
```

What I'm currently doing is using `.pivot_table` with this aggregation function:

```
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(
   index=['foo', 'tak'],
   values=['bar', 'nix'],
   aggfunc = lambda x: list(set(x))
)
```

Then I'm expanding those columns of lists of unique values for each foo-tak group into multiple columns, and concatenating those together in a list comprehension:

```
pd.concat(
   [
       pivot_df[column].apply(pd.Series)
       for column in ['bar', 'nix']
   ],
   axis=1
)
```

Is there a simpler / more direct / more Pythonic way of doing this transformation?

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

i think `apply` with axis=1 + `pd.Series` <-- slow code

use following code for speed up:

```
cols = ['bar', 'nix']

out = pd.concat(
    [df.drop(cols, axis=1)] + 
    [pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col) for col in cols], 
    axis=1
)
```

out

```
     foo      tak bar0  bar1 nix0  nix1
0    one     dgad    B     A    Z  None
1  three  ogfagas    C     A    G  None
2    two   adgadg    C  None    Z     G
```

---

chk with following example

df in the document is multiplied by 100,000 to create a new dataframe.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000).reset_index(drop=True)
```

1. apply, axis=1 + pd.Series

82.65982sec

2. my answer

0.09070sec

Comment: This code does not generate the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop, you can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the data, then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then deduplicate the items per group with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) back to wide form:

```
cols = ['foo', 'tak']

# melt, keep unique combinations, pivot back to wide form
out = (df
   .melt(cols).drop_duplicates()
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(cols+['variable']).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index=cols, columns=['variable', 'n'], values='value')
)

# now we flatten the columns MultiIndex and reset the index
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
out.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
     foo      tak bar_1 bar_2 nix_1 nix_2
0    one     dgad     B     A     Z   NaN
1  three   adgadg     C   NaN     Z     G
2    two  ogfagas     C     A     G   NaN
```

Intermediate after `melt`+`drop_duplicates`+deduplication:

```
# (df.melt(cols).drop_duplicates()
#    .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(cols+['variable']).cumcount().add(1))
# )

      foo      tak variable value  n
0     one     dgad      bar     B  1
2     one     dgad      bar     A  2
3     two  ogfagas      bar     C  1
4     two  ogfagas      bar     A  2
6   three   adgadg      bar     C  1
9     one     dgad      nix     Z  1
12    two  ogfagas      nix     G  1
15  three   adgadg      nix     Z  1
16  three   adgadg      nix     G  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `pd.groupby` and custom group function instead pivoting:

```py
def group_fn(g):
    out = {}
    for c in g.columns:
        for i, v in enumerate(g[c].unique(), 1):
            out[f"{c}_{i}"] = v
    return pd.Series(out.values(), index=out.keys())


out = (
    df.groupby(["foo", "tak"], sort=False)
    .apply(group_fn, include_groups=False)
    .unstack(2)
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     foo      tak bar_1 bar_2 nix_1 nix_2
0    one     dgad     B     A     Z   NaN
1    two  ogfagas     C     A     G   NaN
2  three   adgadg     C   NaN     Z     G
```

Comment: When I ran this code I got a TypeError: group_fn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'.

Comment: @semblable You probably use older version of `pandas` (if you use older version, try to update or remove this `include_groups=False` parameter.